# What is the best Practice Deploying an API Architecture on GCP?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, architecture, cloud, google-cloud-run

So, now I have to deploy the API Product Deployment on GCP, I'm using several Services from this, there are :

1. Cloud Run (Backend)
2. Cloud Endpoints (API Gateway)
3. Cloud SQL (Databases)
4. Cloud Storage (File Storage)

This Architecture was going well, but, from this Architecture, I find this too simple to be considered as an architecture, which I would like to ask, what are the services that make our API architecture look more structured than this?

So this is my API Architecture on GCP

[image: API Architecture]

I need some advice on this Architecture, I'm sorry, my understanding of this architecture is still a little, so I need some advice from you guys

Comment: I don't understand your concern and what do you expect. Great architecture, fully managed, somewhat scalable (Cloud SQL need to scale up manually)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I mean, is there any other option besides this architecture? Such as using Apigee to replace the Cloud Endpoints, or maybe another service to improve this?

Comment: Yes, you have a lot of options to serve this same architecture, different product, more or less managed, more or less expensive, with more or less features. You want to improve it, perfect. But for what? To answer which requirement? Scalability? cost? latency? security? Over-engineering is a bad practice. Do what you need, for now, to meet the requirements!